# Grails - CSS rules not being applied

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I'm developing a Grails app and I'm having a problem with the CSS rules applied to a view. Consider this GSP code:

```
<div id="radio" style="height: 30px">
    <div class="fieldcontain">
        <label style="float: left; width: 25%; overflow: hidden">
            <g:message code="recepcionDeComplejoInstance.tipoDeMineral.label" default="Tipo De Mineral" />

        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-button" style="float: left; width: 75%; overflow: hidden; text-align: start">
        <input type="radio" id="radioComplejo" value="complejo" name="radio" checked="checked"><label for="radioComplejo">COMPLEJO</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioPlomoPlata" value="plomoPlata" name="radio"><label for="radioPlomoPlata">PB-AG</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioZincPlata"  value="zincPlata" name="radio"><label for="radioZincPlata">ZN-AG</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioCobrePlata" value="cobrePlata" name="radio"><label for="radioCobrePlata">CU-AG</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="radio2" style="height: 30px">
    <div class="fieldcontain">
        <label style="float: left; width: 25%; overflow: hidden">
            <g:message code="recepcionDeComplejoInstance.naturalezaMineral.label" default="Naturaleza Mineral" />

        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-button" style="float: left; width: 50%; overflow: hidden; text-align: start">
        <input type="radio" id="radioSulfuro" value="sulfuro" name="radio2" checked="checked"><label for="radioSulfuro">SULFURO</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radioOxido" value="oxido" name="radio2"><label for="radioOxido">OXIDO</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the result:
[image: result]

There are two CSS classes used in the view:

1. `fieldcontain`, that is the default CSS provided by Grails.
2. `ui-button`,declared in the JQuery UI Lightness file
   (jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css)

As you can see the **Naturaleza Mineral** radio buttons don't have the appearance of the **Tipo De Mineral** radio button considering that the same CSS rules are being applied to both radio button groups.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have enable jquery-ui radio button style from javascript by calling `buttonset()`:

```
$( "#radio, #radio2" ).buttonset();
```

Follow this plunker [`example`](http://plnkr.co/edit/08L7R7tzo5E8IXRtaozb?p=preview).

Comment: It works great! But I don't understand the relation between the CSS rules and the buttonset() function.